# Is adding a new feature to a Ethereum client, without altering consensus rules, a creation of a new fork?

Tags: blockchain, nodes, network, validators, softfork

So, if I add new features to my Ethereum client like new ways to Incentivize validators and nodes without altering the consensus rules, and 5 people start trying my Ethereum client, becoming nodes, would I have created a soft fork of the Ethereum protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new features to an Ethereum client without altering the consensus rules would typically not be considered a new fork of the Ethereum protocol. A fork usually refers to a significant divergence in the protocol's rules, often resulting in two separate chains with incompatible consensus rules and transaction histories.
Your client would likely remain compatible with the existing Ethereum network. It would simply introduce additional functionality for nodes and validators, but as long as it maintains compatibility with the existing consensus rules, it wouldn't constitute a fork.

Comment: Can I add a new feature that is outside of the consensus rules like a lottery system where people deposit a minimum of 25 ETH, and maximum 4 people per round, and based on who wins, the other people's ETH is burned, meanwhile the winner gets minted the amount of ETH he deposited? Could request a feature like this one on Ethereum Improvement Proposals?

Comment: You can certainly propose a new feature like this through an Ethereum Improvement Proposal (EIP).  While EIPs are typically associated with protocol-level changes, it is possible to propose broader changes or enhancements that don't directly affect the consensus rules. And it is important to note that such a feature would likely require careful consideration and evaluation within the Ethereum community.

Comment: Basically, it would be compatible with the existing Ethereum clients? And I think that maybe this could be added in a new folder that is called "lottery" or something.